# How do I clean data using pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'd have to `' \\n, *,  ' ==> '\n *'`
but I tried using
`df['Course_content']=df['Course_content'].replace(' \\n, *,  ','\n *',regex=True)`
but it's not working for me

```
>>> df['Course_content'][0]
'The syllabus for this course will cover the following:, \\n, *,  The nature and purpose of cost and management accounting, \\n, *,  Source documents and coding, \\n, *,  Cost classification and measuring, \\n, *,  Recording costs, \\n, *,  Spreadsheets'
>>> df['Course_content']=df['Course_content'].replace(' \\n, *,  ','\n *',regex=True)
>>> df['Course_content'][0]
'The syllabus for this course will cover the following:, \\n, *,  The nature and purpose of cost and management accounting, \\n, *,  Source documents and coding, \\n, *,  Cost classification and measuring, \\n, *,  Recording costs, \\n, *,  Spreadsheets'
>>>
```

I also try with below code but it's also not working for me

```
d = {
'Not Mentioned':'',
"\r\n": "\n",
"\\r": "\n",
'\u00a0':' ',
' \\n, *,':  "\n * ",
' \\n,':'\n',
}
df=df.replace(d.keys(),d.values(),regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the 2 parameters into r-string and add a `\` before the `*` on the first parameter. This is necessary because `\` and `*` are special meta-characters in regex, you have to use extra `\` and/or r-string to 'escape' these characters to their literal values.

You can use:

```
df['Course_content'] = df['Course_content'].replace(r' \\n, \*,  ', r'\n *', regex=True)
```

### Demo:

```
data = {'Course_content': ['The syllabus for this course will cover the following:, \\n, *,  The nature and purpose of cost and management accounting, \\n, *,  Source documents and coding, \\n, *,  Cost classification and measuring, \\n, *,  Recording costs, \\n, *,  Spreadsheets']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Course_content'] = df['Course_content'].replace(r' \\n, \*,  ', r'\n *', regex=True)
```

Result:

```
print(df['Course_content'][0])


'The syllabus for this course will cover the following:,\n *The nature and purpose of cost and management accounting,\n *Source documents and coding,\n *Cost classification and measuring,\n *Recording costs,\n *Spreadsheets'
```